# Multiple JAR Application Over Webstart

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have a webstart application that uses ProcessBuilder to launch several other application jars from the main app. The whole purpose of the main app is to kick off these two other apps. I am certain the jars are all making it over webstart (no missing cache elements from the console when it launches) but when I try to launch the application jars, they don't seem to launch or run or anything. No exceptions either. I am able to run the app locally when double clicking the jnlp locally but when I do it over the server it doesn't work and gives no signs of why.

My best guess is that it can't find the jars from the path name given over webstart when they are loaded in as java JAR resources in the cache, though I'm not really sure how to deal with it or reference them to start those secondary JAR Apps.

Comment: Is it possible your Web Start application does not have the required permissions to access the RuntimeExec features? I'm not confident they have that permission by default as it would create a serious security hole.

Comment: Well the apps are all signed and have all-permissions listed in the manifest. I'm using ProcessBuilder.start() to try and call the jars but I don't think the paths are correct since the jars are loaded into the java cache. I tested this by pointing processbuilder to the jars I have locally on my machine and it ran fine through the browser. I guess I just need to know how to access/reference the cached versions.

Comment: You can find the location of your JARs using `YourClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()` Do that for each of the classes in the JARs you need. Or do it for the main one, and the others should be in the same directory as well.

Comment: Ok. Will attempt and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewTFinnell Caution: [getCodeSource() may return null.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html#getCodeSource())

Comment: @AndrewTFinnell Well I tried it out in multiple fashions and was able to get a URL that linked to the local machine server. I tried to plug this in to the ProcessBuilder object calling java -jar URL/myJar.jar and it did not start the jar. I tried to do this via the command line as well and got "Unable to access jarfile".

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried and the full output you got. You can obfuscate it if you want.

Comment: @Robin All the things I've tried were variations of the above as well as. GetResource(). From that I get a URL of the local machine with a path to the jar. As mentioned previously I tried to call Java -jar URL via process builder and cmdline and it wouldn't work. I was unable to get a fully fledged path from the URL which is something else that I attempted. When converting the url to a file and getting the path, it just gave the url minus the port and IP.

Comment: I'm having trouble guessing what you mean by "a URL of the local machine". Please provide an EXAMPLE.

Comment: http://IPAddr:8080/Path/To/File/SystemApp.jar. Path to file is relative to the webserver.

Comment: So I'm testing using a browser that goes to 192.168.0.50:8080/hmi/launch.html. Clicking that it launches 192.168.0.50:8080/hmi/launch.jnlp. From where it pulls my jars and starts the app. If I call myclass.class.getProtectedDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation() it returns 192.168.0.50:8080/hmi/myapp.jar. So I then use that in a process builder call of Java - jar URL (edited for myapp2). Which didnt work. Also tried to getAbsolutePath which just returned hmi/myapp.jar.